# d3 mouse event return element

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Trying to learn d3 (v5) here

I'm trying to add an event listener to a group of path of voronoi that I generated.

I wanted to use d3 mouse event but i couldn't access the element that trigger the event.

Here is the code:

```
svg
.append("g")
.attr("class","cells")
.selectAll("path")
.data(voronoi.polygons(vertices))
.enter().append("path")
.attr("d",(d)=>{return "M" + d.join("L") + "Z"})
.on("mousemove",()=>{console.log(this)})
```

consol.log just gave me the whole window, I also tried using d3.mouse(this), which i saw in some v3,4 examples, but it gave me this error

`Uncaught TypeError: t.getBoundingClientRect is not a function`
also tried d3.svg.mouse(this)
`Uncaught TypeError: d3.svg.mouse is not a function`
I also tried d3.touch(this), because... why not
and it just return null 
  
I want to try to access the path that the mouse is over, and change the style/attribute.
i know i can do it in css, but I'm learning d3, so I would like to know how to do that.
  
thank you all  
  
  
github link to the code:
https://github.com/Sidchou/d3-exercise

Answer (score 2):

Try to use the standard function, because arrow functions use the outer lexical scope:

```
.on("mousemove", function(){ console.log(this) })
```

Comment: OMG that worked!! thank you! i thought they usually use arrow function for d3 
><
also, i found out that ```d3.event.target``` will work too, but its good to know